# How to open local apache website to the world?

Tags: networking, iptables

I'm trying to enable HTTP port to be accessible from outside of my network.
I currently have a public IP from my ISP.

Do I need to set this up using iptables?

sudo iptables -vL -n

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 91728 packets, 101M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 64927 packets, 5892K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

sudo ip addr list

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f0:de:f1:11:03:95 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f0:7b:cb:9f:c6:f2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.101/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global wlan0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::f27b:cbff:fe9f:c6f2/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

sudo ss -nptl src :80

```
State       Recv-Q Send-Q                                                                      Local Address:Port                                                                        Peer Address:Port 
LISTEN      0      128                                                                                    :::80                                                                                    :::*      users:(("apache2",1267,4),("apache2",1266,4),("apache2",1265,4),("apache2",1264,4),("apache2",1263,4),("apache2",1249,4))
```

sudo ip route

```
default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlan0  proto static 
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.101  metric 9
```

---

I also invite you to check another post :-)
https://askubuntu.com/questions/574726/problem-with-package-phpmyadmin-error-when-trying-to-create-table-in-phpmyadmi

Comment: *NOT* using capslock is a good starting point

Comment: apply_corrections( );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have the public IP bound to an interface of the machine running a webserver. It's actually configured on your router. Since it's doing the Network Adress Translation (NAT), no new external connections to this public will reach your internal machines by default.

You'll need to do 2 things to make this work:

1. Allow incoming HTTP[S] connections to the machine running the webserver.

.

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

This opens both port 80/tcp and 443/tcp for incoming connections. From your question, it looks like you're not running a firewall at all - I recommend you look into it sooner than later.

2. You will also need to forward ports (80 and 443 if you wish) from the router to the machine running the webserver (in addition to the 2 netfilter rules above).

I don't know what router you have but this should help:

- External IP: your public IP
- External port: 80/tcp
- Internal IP: 192.168.0.101
- Internal port: 80/tcp

If after doing this you're still having problems, please post the output of

```
sudo iptables -vL -n
sudo ss -nptl src :80
sudo ip addr list
sudo ip route
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! : ) Ok done with first 2 commands. How can I test it now? Allegedly when I try to call IP / result of http://whatismyipaddress.com/  I em getting no response in browser.

Comment: Please post the output of commands in my answer and I'll take a look.

Comment: Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 9523 packets, 2654K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     Please post the output of commands in my answer and I'source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 9874 packets, 1190... too long

Comment: State       Recv-Q Send-Q                                                                      Local Address:Port                                                                        Peer Address:Port 
LISTEN      0      128                                                                                    :::80                                                                                    :::*      users:(("apache2",1267,4),("apache2",1266,4),("apache2",1265,4),("apache2",1264,4),("apache2",1263,4),("apache2",1249,4))

Comment: 1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f0:de:f1:11:03:95 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f0:7b:cb:9f:c6:f ... too long

Comment: default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlan0  proto static 
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.101  metric 9

Comment: PS. Regarding hardware - everything is on 1 lenovo T410i laptop and Ubuntu.

Comment: Could you please move the commands' results to your question and format them as code (select the text, press Ctrl+K). It will definitely be cleaner.

Comment: Anyway, from the output of `ip route`, you don't have the public IP configured on the machine running the webserver, so you'll need to follow the last part of my answer - forwarding ports from your router to this machine. PS. your firewall's INPUT chain has an ACCEPT policy, meaning the rules I suggested weren't even necessary.